# Derivative of trig functions

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, derivatives

I'm having trouble for the derivative of this trig function and got $40 \sin x \frac1{1000\pi} \cos x$ for the function

$\frac{20\sin^2 x}{1000\pi}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{20\sin^2(x)}{1000\pi}\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{\sin^2(x)}{50\pi}\right)=$$
$$\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin^2(x)\right)}{50\pi}=\frac{\sin(x)\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin(x)\right)\right)}{25\pi}=$$
$$\frac{\sin(x)\left(\cos(x)\right)}{25\pi}=\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{25\pi}=\frac{\sin(2x)}{50\pi}$$

---

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(10-10\cos(x)\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(10\right)-10\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\cos(x)\right)=$$
$$0-10\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\cos(x)\right)=-10\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\cos(x)\right)=$$
$$-10\left(-\sin(x)\right)=10\sin(x)$$

Comment: I keep getting 10-10cosx as derivative

Comment: @Ackblah From what function do you want to get the derivative?

Comment: The same one you did with the 20sin^2

Comment: @Ackblah See my edit!

Comment: Now you can close your question, by clicking on the 'v' sign!

Comment: Where's the v sign, sorry lol

Comment: Under the downvote sign ;)

Comment: Oh you mean the check mark